# Jexl parallel processing example

Tags: java, jexl

I need to do several actions at the same time in Jexl. In official guide I found annotation **@parallel**:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html
But I didn't find any examples how to use it.

Can anyone provide some examples?

I thought it will work like this:

```
@parallel { a.someMethod() }
@parallel { b.someMethod() }
```

But seems like it's still working sequentially.
Second example I've tried, still not working:

```
var loopFunction = function(title){
    var i = 0;
    logger:info("Starting "+title);
    while(i<100) {
        logger:info(title+"="+i);
        utils:sleep(25);
        i += 1;
    }
    logger:info("Ending "+title);
}

@parallel loopFunction('i');
@parallel loopFunction('j');
```

Comment: When you say "It's still working sequentially", what does it means ? How did you checked ?

Comment: I've tried to add big loops (5 secs) to this method with logging. And I got `b.someMethod()` log after `a.someMethod()` log.

Comment: Maybe try with a random time in your `utils.sleep` (so that i and j has a different waiting time). If it not fix the problem, I will let jexl professionals help you :P

Comment: Tried different timings, different length of loop. Still it prints

    `Starting i
    i=1
    ...
    i=100
    Ending i
    Starting j
    j=1
    ...
    j=250
    Ending j`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's an example of annotation, in [jexl code](https://github.com/apache/commons-jexl/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=processAnnotation&type=) it seems that only `synchronized` is implemented.

> ```
> @Override
> public Object processAnnotation(String name, Object[] args,Callable<Object> statement) throws Exception {
>
>     if ("synchronized".equals(name)) {
>         final Object arg = args[0];
>         synchronized(arg) {
>             return statement.call();
>         }
>     }
>     throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown annotation " + name);
> }
> ```

There's a parallel test but it uses `ExecutorService`:

> ```
> /**
>      * Run same test function in NTHREADS in parallel.
>      * @param ctask the task / test
>      * @param loops number of loops to perform
>      * @param cache whether jexl cache is used or not
>      * @throws Exception if anything goes wrong
>      */
>     @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
>     void runThreaded(Class<? extends Task> ctask, int loops, boolean cache) throws Exception {
>         if (loops == 0) {
>             loops = MIX.length;
>         }
>         if (!cache) {
>             jexl = jexlNoCache;
>         } else {
>             jexl = jexlCache;
>         }
>         java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService execs = java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREADS);
>         List<Callable<Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Integer>>(NTHREADS);
>         for (int t = 0; t < NTHREADS; ++t) {
>             tasks.add(jexl.newInstance(ctask, loops));
>         }
>         // let's not wait for more than a minute
>         List<Future<Integer>> futures = execs.invokeAll(tasks, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
>         // check that all returned loops
>         for (Future<Integer> future : futures) {
>             Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(loops), future.get());
>         }
>     }
> ```